# VBA code to export data from Excel to corresponding SQL field

Tags: excel, vba, t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an Excel VBA program that scans barcodes to print labels. What I am trying to do is write a sub that when execeuted with the rest of the code, will take Today's date and insert it into a specific date field in the SQL databse. To further explain the Excel program uses an order number which corresponds with an order number in our database. I'm not 100% sure how to proceed with this and can provide additional information if it's helpful.

```
|OrderNo| |TodaysDateFromExcel|   
033707     7/15/2019
```

My VBA code I have so far

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

Dim sDate As Date

sDate= Today()

'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ANF-M2MCLIENT;Initial Catalog=ExcelDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

 conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (TodaysDate) values ('" & sDate & "')"

MsgBox "Today's Date imported."

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

End sub
```

Comment: Look into [ADODB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I have the ADOODB connection setup. My question is more centered around getting the date from the VBA code to the corresponding OrderNo in the database. @MathieuGuindon

Comment: From your question it's impossible to tell that you have an ADODB connection configured. Please include the relevant code so we know which *specific* part there's a problem with. Do you have an `INSERT` SQL statement written? Are you asking about how to parameterize it? Very hard to tell as it stands...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon edited with more information

Comment: Great! Looks like you're on the right track, are you getting an error on `conn.Execute`? SQL Server can get today's date with `getdate()`, so I'm struggling to see what the Excel worksheet is bringing to the table, or why `TodaysDate` even needs to be a thing. Or do you mean to *insert/update* an `Orders` table with an `OrderDate` value coming from an Excel worksheet?

Comment: Our end users only have access to the Excel sheet/Program.This event procedure will go into the last step. So event 1 prints the label of the OrderNo, event 2 clears the form, and the third event that my question is on takes the current date and inserts it into the table of the corresponding OrderNo.

Comment: In a normalized schema you would have an `Orders` table with a `CustomerId` column; an `OrderNo` field would belong to the `Orders` table, not `Customers`. Can you further edit to describe what your schema looks like? It's hard to visualize what the T-SQL needs to do without knowing anything about the tables involved. As for today's date, I was just pointing out that you could `INSERT INTO table(TodaysDate) VALUES (getdate())` if the date really needs to be *today's date*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cn_ADO As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd_ADO As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd_ADO = New ADODB.Command

    Dim Dbconn As String

    Dim SQLQuery As String
    Dim strWhere As String


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim jOffset As Integer
    Dim iStartRow As Integer

    'Data Columns
     Dim strOrderNumber As String
     Dim strOrderDate As String

    jOffset = 3
    iStartRow = 2
    i = iStartRow

Dbconn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ANF-M2MCLIENT;Initial Catalog=ExcelDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"


 Set cn_ADO = New ADODB.Connection

 cn_ADO.Open Dbconn

While Cells(i, jOffset).Value <> ""
    strOrderNumber = Cells(i, 0 + jOffset).Value
    strOrderDate = Cells(i, 1 + jOffset).Value

    strWhere = "OrderNumber = " & strOrderNumber

         'Update Statement

         SQLQuery = "update dbo.Orders " & _
                    "set " & _
                    "OrderDate = '" & strOrderDate & "' " & _
                    "where " & strWhere

    cmd_ADO.CommandText = SQLQuery
    cmd_ADO.ActiveConnection = cn_ADO
    cmd_ADO.Execute

    i = i + 1
    Wend


       Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
        Set cn_ADO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with the assumption that you have a somewhat normalized schema - something like this:

[image: customers -> orders]

If you want to `INSERT` a new `Order` record, you need to know what customer `Id` it's for (and any other foreign keys that might be defined for an `Order`).

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (CustomerId, OrderNumber, OrderDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

If your `Customers` table has a unique key e.g. `CustomerNumber`, then you can get the `Id` foreign key from that:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (CustomerId, OrderNumber, OrderDate) 
SELECT c.Id, ?, ?
FROM dbo.Customers c
WHERE c.Number = ?
```

If you want to `UPDATE` an existing `Order` record, you need to know what order `Id` to update - assuming there's a *natural key* defining `OrderNumber` as unique across `Order` records, you can update an order's `OrderDate` given an `OrderNumber` - the SQL command string would look like this:

```
UPDATE o SET o.OrderDate = ? FROM dbo.Orders o WHERE o.OrderNumber = ?
```

That needs two parameters, and it would look something like this in VBA:

```vb
Public Sub SaveOrderDate(ByVal orderNumber As String, ByVal orderDate As Date)

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 'note: avoid auto-instantiated "As New" objects
    conn.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
    conn.Open

    Const sql As String = "UPDATE o SET o.OrderDate = ? WHERE OrderNumber = ?"

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdTypeText
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adDate, Value:=orderDate)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarChar, Value:=orderNumber)

    cmd.Execute
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

And then you would invoke it from your macro, like this:

```vb
Public Sub Macro1()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    SaveOrderDate Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value, Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value
    MsgBox "Order updated!"
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong, couldn't update the order."
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit 'break here to debug (F9 to toggle a breakpoint)
    Resume 'make this the current statement to step through errorring SaveOrderDate call
End Sub
```

Note: untested air-code.

Comment: Where there are "?" would I set those `=` to the parameter values from my excel worksheet cells?

Comment: The `?` are ordinal parameter placeholders that ADODB understands as such - never concatenate user inputs into SQL statements. XKCD has a [classic comic](https://xkcd.com/327/) explaining what you're allowing to happen when you do that. The parameters are handled server-side, passed to the command through its `Parameters` collection, as shown in the example code above.

Comment: With parameterized ADODB commands, you don't have to worry about escaping single quotes and date literals: that's for the server to worry about. When you take this task client-side, you become vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and annoying bugs whenever your inputs need to actually have a legit single-quote character. Mr. O'Neil and Mrs.Null will be very pleased that you properly parameterize your data access code.

Comment: @David if you have SSMS and enough privs on the server to create a stored procedure, consider writing one that takes parameters for the values that need to be inserted/updated. That way your VBA code has no SQL statements other than stored procedure names, and you keep database concerns on the database side of things.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll take all of this into account as I continue to figure out the best course of action to take.